# Combinatorial Interpretation of Generalized Stirling numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I know the combinatorial interpretation of first, and second order Stirling numbers (#of k cycles of n items, and #of partitions n items into k subsets). Is there an interpretation for the generalized Stirling numbers?

Comment: did you try at least googling?

Comment: Don't forget to add your findings (and references!) to the Wikipedia page: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Combinatorial Interpretation of Generalized Stirling Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Lang/lang.pdf) (2009)

> A combinatorial interpretation of the earlier studied generalized
>   Stirling numbers, emerging in a normal ordering problem and its
>   inversion, is given. It involves unordered forests of certain types of
>   labeled trees. Partition number arrays related to such forests are
>   also presented.

Answer (score 0):

Similar numbers were introduced in the article [On a generalization of Stirling numbers](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth05.pdf) (2002). They have combinatorial interpretations in terms of trees and necklaces.